# Identify this set: yellow and light grey plates

Tags: set-identification

I would like to find what set these are for.
Yellow, light gray, black, white.
No bag number.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on:

- 4162 tile 1 x 8 white, and
- 50305 wedge plate 3 x 8 yellow

This is [set 6912 Super Soarer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6912-1).

[image: Set 6912]